# file_get_content('php://input') return wrong data

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

i want to get full json data sent to my page, im using file_get_contents('php://input') and i convert it into json using json_decode(). But for discord embeds, file_get_contents() return wrong data.

Json string : `{"embeds":[{"title":"Hello!","description":"Hi!"}]}`

file_get_contents() return : `embeds=title&embeds=description`

i use python requests module to send json :

```py
import requests

data = {"embeds":[{"title":"Hello!","description":"Hi! :grinning:"}]}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post('https://example.com', data=data, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

alternative to file_get_contents() or something else ?

Comment: I think the problem is made by the front-end. Can you attach the code that you are using for sending data?

Comment: First you extract embeds then in embeds, you extract the json data at index 0 of embeds which is now your fully formed json data.

Comment: @AmirrezaNoori i use print_r() function to get file_get_contents() return

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($data);

Comment: I mean, how do you send this JSON to the PHP page?

Comment: oh i use python requests module @AmirrezaNoori

Comment: Can you attach the python code to your question? because the PHP code seems true. Maybe the problem is from the python requests module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from the request in the Python script. `data` parameter should send as a string for JSON mode. add `import json` to your code and use `data=json.dumps(data)` instead of `data=data`.

More information about `json.dumps` is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
r = requests.post('https://example.com', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```